# Create Devise user without confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I was wondering if there are any tutorials or best practices to creating `devise` users without confirmation for email or password.

Basically I want something similar to [Tumblr's](https://www.tumblr.com/) landing page--ask for email and password, and then just let the user have an account, not confirmation or anything else necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `confirmable` module of devise from your model and also these columns from your table

```
confirmation_token, confirmed_at, confirmation_sent_at, unconfirmed_email
```

Comment: So then I create the account with something like: `build_account(params[:account] = {email: @application.email_address, password: @application.password})` ?

Comment: Yes then you can proceed with the normal sign up

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `confirmable` from your Devise Model. 
if you have a User Model being authenticated by devise.
You will need to change your `app/models/user.rb` and remove `confirmable`

Comment: If you'd like me to take a closer look in the next 30 min, click to my profile and connect with me on video chat.